# Wordpress page jump

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer

Hi I am making a website for my college using `Wordpress`. The site content is made through `Visual Composer` plugin. I am having a problem with page jump using `<a id="#section"></a>`. There is a page with full of student thumbnails
`http://www.abcdef.com/people/` where all the photos of people are linked to a particular section in the page `http://www.abcdef.com/department/`.

If you click on **Person 1** photo, the following page with Person 1's section should be loaded `http://abcdef.com/department/#tapan`. Instead, it always loads to the bottom of the page. But once you are in this page and if you change the URL and replace the `#person1` with `#person2` or `#person3` it scrolls to the particular section.

I am not able to understand why it is not scrolling when loaded for the first time. Any insights?

Comment: It is actually working for me in Chrome.

Comment: I see the problem in safari. There is a problem with the auto scroll script when it first loads the page most likely. looking into it.

Comment: Oh my, is this a browser issue? Chrome and IE is doing it well.

Comment: Never mind, now its working with Firefox also. The scroll2id plugin is working like a charm. Thanks a lot. Please reply to this comment, because I have to delete this post since the site is not supposed to be live yet.

Comment: just delete the links to your site. I would appreciate some points for answering and would be very grateful. Thank you and good luck with finishing the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling "smooth scroll on click".
The option located here:
Appearance -> Customize -> Global Settings -> Links style and effects